# Tesseract stops processing after error in image list

Tags: tesseract

Is there any way to config Tesseract OCR to process all the images inside one list without stopping execution if a problem/error is encountered?

```
Example 
> tesseract list.txt stdout 
  Page 0 img1.jpg 
  Word_0 
  Image file 4319.jpg cannot be read!
  Error during processing.
```

The list contains several other images but the program stops at the first error =S

I will appreciate any recommendation.

I am using Tesseract 5.0.0 for Windows (https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide valid input for tesseract. If your file list is not correct, why tesseract should solve it?

Correct way is that you should validate file list in advance and make your decision (e.g. remove not existing files).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your point, however, to verify thousands of images requires time (not only to check if the file exists but also confirm it is a valid image). It is a waste of time considering the following two points: 1. Tesseract already does that validation for each image. 2. Regarding coding, its a matter of a try catch sentence to implement that behavior which would be very useful